# SelectedMode for GridControl ( DevExpress )

Tags: c#, devexpress

I want to set the selection mode for my grid control. But there is not SelectedMode or same option in properties. Can you help me please ? I don't find anything on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A GridControl can have many GridViews within it. You need to set the selection mode on the GridView. For example, the MultiSelect property is in the properties under Options -> OptionsSelection for GridView.

Comment: it is possible to select full row when I click on a cell ?

Comment: I believe this is the behavior if Options.OptionsSelection.EnableAppearanceFocusedRow is true (which is the default value.)

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find any information about grid's selection feature: [Selections Overview](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument711).
Also I believe the [End-User Capabilities: Selecting Rows/Cards](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument820) article will be helpful.